# Lista de Números

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde 
Estou estudando Js.

Criei um código que mostra uma lista de números de 1 até 10 porém não quero que no meu resultado seja mostrado os números 2 e 9.

Meu problema é não saber expressar esta duvida nas pesquisa ou o nome/termo que este meu problema se enquadra.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>

    function pulaLinha() {

        document.write("<br>"); 
        document.write("<br>"); 
    }

    function mostra(frase) {

        document.write(frase);
        pulaLinha();
    }

var i = 0
var cont = (i +1);

    while (cont <= 10) {
        mostra (cont++);


}

</script>
```

Comment: Você precisa realmente usar o `while`, não pode ser um `for`?

Comment: Boa tarde Pablo.
Estou estudando então por conta própria descobri o "for" hoje ( rsrs), por isso gostaria de encontrar uma forma com o while.

Grato

Comment: o que você precisa é utilizar o condicional `If`, exemplo: Se o valor for igual a 2 ou 9 então faça algo se não faça outra coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi seria apenas não chamar a função se for o número 2 ou 9, ficando assim:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>

    function pulaLinha() {

        document.write("<br>"); 
        document.write("<br>"); 
    }

    function mostra(frase) {

        document.write(frase);
        pulaLinha();
    }

var i = 0
var cont = (i +1);

      while (cont <= 10) {
    if(cont !== 2 && cont !==9 ){
        mostra (cont);    
    }
    cont++;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Só que dessa forma você terá um laço infinito, pois quando o cont chegar em 2 ele não vai mais incrementar. veja como fiz https://jsfiddle.net/mkzdn5q1/

Comment: Opa muito obrigado.
Era isto que estava procurando como devo chamar isto !==, negação ?

Comment: Gilson respondi sua pergunta e coloquei alguns links para que você possa ter uma base maior.

Comment: Tem razão @PabloTondolodeVargas editei

Comment: @GilsonRodrigo, sim isso é negação

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente pense na lógica que precisa, basicamente chegaremos a seguinte ideia:

*Se o contador for igual a 2 ou for igual a 9 não devo exibi-lo*

OU

*Se o contador for diferente de 2 e diferente de 9 devo exibi-lo*

Próximo passo é descobrir como fazer isso em `javascript` basicamente você precisirá utilizar uma [estrutura condicional](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) combinada com um [operador de comparação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_comparacao).

Resultando nisso:

```
if(cont != 2 && cont != 9){ 
   //Se for diferente de 2 e 9
   //Chamar função para exibir cont
}
```

Veja o exemplo completo, aplicado a seu código:

```js
function pulaLinha() {
    document.write("<br>"); 
    document.write("<br>"); 
}

function mostra(frase) {
    document.write(frase);
    pulaLinha();
}

var cont = 1;
while (cont <= 10) {

  if(cont != 2 && cont != 9){ //Se for diferente de 2 e diferente de 9
    mostra (cont);            //Exibo  o contador
  }
  cont++;                     //Sempre incrimento 1 ao contador
}
```